# Как получить имя пользователя во всех падежах | VK_API Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Всем привет! Есть такая необходимость, что в некоторых местах надо бы использовать другой `name_case` для одного и того же пользователя.

Каждый раз выполнять `vk.users.get` как минимум не красиво *(как максимум - приведёт к более долгому выполнению кода)*, а делать что-то на подобие такого(ниже) - приведёт либо к возврату с ошибкой "слишком много запросов за секунду", либо вообще работать не будет:

```
# Что это за завтрак из макарон?
def get_all_namecases_user(user_id):
    return {
        'nom' : { 
            'first_name' : vk.users.get (
                user_ids = user_id,
                name_case = 'nom'
                )[0]['first_name'],
            'last_name' : vk.users.get (
                user_ids = user_id,
                name_case = 'nom'
                )[0]['last_name']
            },
        'gen' : {
            'first_name' : vk.users.get (
                user_ids = user_id,
                name_case = 'gen'
                )[0]['first_name'],
            'last_name' : vk.users.get (
                user_ids = user_id,
                name_case = 'gen'
                )[0]['last_name']
            },
        'dat' : {
            'first_name' : vk.users.get (
                user_ids = user_id,
                name_case = 'dat'
                )[0]['first_name'],
            'last_name' : vk.users.get (
                user_ids = user_id,
                name_case = 'dat'
                )[0]['last_name']
            },
        'acc' : {
            'first_name' : vk.users.get (
                user_ids = user_id,
                name_case = 'acc'
                )[0]['first_name'],
            'last_name' : vk.users.get (
                user_ids = user_id,
                name_case = 'acc'
                )[0]['last_name']
            },
        'ins' : { 
            'first_name' : vk.users.get (
                user_ids = user_id,
                name_case = 'ins'
                )[0]['first_name'],
            'last_name' : vk.users.get (
                user_ids = user_id,
                name_case = 'ins'
                )[0]['last_name']
            },
        'abl' : {
            'first_name' : vk.users.get (
                user_ids = user_id,
                name_case = 'abl'
                )[0]['first_name'],
            'last_name' : vk.users.get (
                user_ids = user_id,
                name_case = 'abl'
                )[0]['last_name']
            }
        }
```

Как можно выйти из этой ситуации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, знакомы ли Вы с методом, таким как `execute`, но хочу сказать, чтобы не делать велосипеды и тратить время на много запросов, можно воспользоваться им, вот [пример](https://vk.cc/9aJr0d):

```
var user_id = 1,
    i = 0;

var inp = ["nom", "gen", "dat", "acc", "ins", "abl"],
    out = [];

while (i < inp.length)
{
    out = out + API.users.get({
        user_ids: user_id,
        name_case: inp[i]
    });

    i = i + 1;
}

return out;
```

В результате мы получим массив объектов со всеми значениями в нужных падежах.

Comment: Как-то на Python не похоже.... Кажется это JS...

Comment: Все верно. Читайте подробно про метод Execute